# How to avoid the column name with lines displaying while calling sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail

I'm new to stored procedure. I've tried to mail by reading a table and did the below query

```
create procedure mailtouser
as
  declare @data varchar(max),
  @user varchar(max)
  as
    set @data='set nocount on;select col_name from tbl_name where id=1;set nocount off;'
    set @user='user@example.com'
    set @query=
    exec sp_send_dbmail
           @profile_name  =  'profile',
           @recipients  =  @user,
           @subject  =  'automail',
       @execute_query_database  =  'database',
       @query = @data;
   end
end
```

exec mailtouser
go

while executing this script, i'm getting mail

as

```
col_name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datas.
```

**how to avoid this col_name and lines. i want that data alone in mail.**

Answer (score 0):

First, are you actually naming a database as [database]?  It should be something like [AdventureWorks2012].

Second, the query will execute and return results.  You do not need @execute_query_database if you use three part notation [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Address].

Third, there are other parameters that go along with this option.  Check them out.

@query_result_header 
 @query_result_width 
 @query_result_separator 
 @exclude_query_output

On the other hand, if you want to take full control, change the body format to HTML.

Run the query inside an SET statement to format the data the way you want.

```
-- Send with embedded html table containing query data
DECLARE @VAR_HTML NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
SET @VAR_HTML =
N'<h1>Work Order Report<h1>' +
N'<table border="1">' +
N'<tbody><tr><th>Work Order ID</th><th>Product ID</th>' +
N'<th>Name</th><th>Order Qty</th><th>Due Date</th>' +
N'<th>Expected Revenue</th></tr>' +
CAST ( ( SELECT td = wo.WorkOrderID, '',
td = p.ProductID, '',
td = p.Name, '',
td = wo.OrderQty, '',
td = wo.DueDate, '',
td = (p.ListPrice - p.StandardCost) * wo.OrderQty
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.WorkOrder as wo
JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product AS p
ON wo.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE DueDate > '2006-04-30'
AND DATEDIFF(dd, '2006-04-30', DueDate) < 2
ORDER BY DueDate ASC,
(p.ListPrice - p.StandardCost) * wo.OrderQty DESC
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</tbody></table>' 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='john@craftydba.com',
@subject = 'Work Order List',
@body = @VAR_HTML,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Sincerely

J